# Status bar in php7 and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using a status bar already formatted by percentage. I am currently working with PHP7.1 and status bar in jQuery.

Status bar 1 to 25 is blue, 25 to 50 is green, 50 to 75 is orange, 75 to 100 is red.

I thought of doing many "if and else" or "Switch and Case" I find it crazy to check out many variables.

I researched the community here and found nothing.

Is there a clever way to do this?

I have to use jQuery and PHP.

Thank you very much.

```
<?php
    $limit=3000;
    $used=1200;
    $percentage = $used / $limit * 100;
    $percentage = round($percentage, 0)
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bar').barfiller({ barColor: '#0080ff' });
    });
</script>

<div id="bar" class="barfiller">
<div class="tipWrap">
<span class="tip"></span>
</div>
<span class="fill" data-percentage="<?php echo $percentage; ?>"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: this sounds like you're getting or planning on getting data from somewhere else, what is the intended source to be (from)? or am I wrong?

Comment: Instead of using if/else or switch statements, you could do this:
`$barColor = in_array($percentage, range(0, 25)) ? '#0000FF' : '';`
`$barColor = in_array($percentage, range(26, 50)) ? '#00FF00' : $barColor;`, you'll need a line for every color you're planning to use..

Comment: The answer comes as JSON has already formatted, I just need to find a clever solution.

Comment: this might be a JSON question also. Question's unclear for me and I will be of no help with JS/JSON.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The question already this format do not need to do anything just wanted the comparison.

Comment: @JeroenGroenveld I'll test your interesting idea.

Comment: I have added an shorter answer, which is a lot better than the one i mentioned above. Thanks to @subhasis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP equivalent for @subhasis his answer"

```
$colors = ['#faa', '#afa', '#cfc', '#afd'];
$barColor = $colors[intval(($percentage == 100 ? --$percentage : $percentage) / 25)];
```

Comment: php will not refresh the progress bar %, can only do in js

Comment: @LeoTahk If you look at the code OP provided, the percentage is calculated when you load the page, so it doesn't really matter if you calculate the bar color in Javascript or PHP. In both cases it will only be updated when you reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep an array of colors like

```
const colors = ['#faa', '#afa', '#cfc', '#afd'];

const statusBar = $('.fill');
let index = parseInt(parseInt(statusBar.text()) / 25);
if (index == colors.length) {
    index--;
}
statusBar.css('background', colors[index]);
```

Comment: You will have to decrease the percentage with 1. Because if you percentage is at 100 the program will try to get the 4th element in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JeroenGroenveld I liked your idea and it worked, thank you very much :-)